# Joomla - template dissapearing

Tags: css, templates, joomla, joomla1.5

I have a Joomla Website located at http://www.MikeSilvis.com, and upon going to the site initially everything looks fine. However if you go into the site and click any link say web-design

You can see that the default template is no longer being displayed. I have tried changing to a different template but that does not seem to help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I've just visited the site and clicked on the 'web-design' link and others and do not see a change in template/style. Might it be a case of your account being logged in and having a different member/admin template setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer to my question. I should have updated this a long time ago.

Something with the URL Rewriting engine built into Joomla, was throwing errors. I turned it off and everything was back to normal!

Thanks for your help though.